# Import Error: Trying to understand the symbol that is not being found

Tags: python, c++

I am modifying someone else's code, and getting an error that the original code does not give me. After setting up a file called PyTransNewEk.so, I try to import it, leading to

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/joe/Downloads/EkPyTransportDist/PyTransport/PyTrans//lib/python/PyTransNewEk.so, 2): Symbol not found: __Z8r8_rkf45PFvdPdS_S_S_S_S_S_S_bEiS_S_S_dS_diS_S_S_
Referenced from: /Users/joe/Downloads/EkPyTransportDist/PyTransport/PyTrans//lib/python/PyTransNewEk.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/joe/Downloads/EkPyTransportDist/PyTransport/PyTrans//lib/python/PyTransNewEk.so
```

I have seen some similar issues online, eg issues with linking with boost.python, but in that case "boost" appeared in the symbol. I notice the integrator I'm using "rkf45" appears in it, but I don't understand what it means.

Comment: Try `ldd /Users/joe/Downloads/EkPyTransportDist/PyTransport/PyTrans//lib/python/PyTransNewEk.so`. Or if I'm not mistaking, that looks like an *OSX* path. There try `otool -L /Users/joe/Downloads/EkPyTransportDist/PyTransport/PyTrans//lib/python/PyTransNewEk.so`.

Comment: It is OSX (I should have clarified). Output is
    `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 104.1.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)`

Comment: Any ideas @CristiFati ?

Comment: What's the same command output on the machine where it works?

Comment: My computer is not working at the moment (getting repaired today) but I am almost certain it was the same. (That is, the output on my machine, for the original code, which runs without this import error)